# Check if any of loop's insides returns 1 and hold it until the whole loop is 0 again

Tags: array, loop

I'm new to this, so, please, don't crucify me.

I have a function that checks if an entry in multilevel array is in a certain range. Using FOR loop I check the whole array with this function, which gives me true/false value for each record.

And now the problem:
I need to check if ANY entry in that loop returns true and hold it until every result of that loop is false again.

Any tips?

Thanks a lot.

There is my for loop:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arrayTop; i++){
for(int j = 0; j < arrayDay; j++){
  for(int k = 0; k < arrayTime; k++){
    timeCompare(timeArray[i][j][k][0], timeArray[i][j][k][1], timeArray[i][j][k][2], timeArray[i][j][k][3], timeArray[i][j][k][4], timeArray[i][j][k][5], timeArray[i][j][k][6]);

    //Serial.print(i);Serial.print(j);Serial.print(k);Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(compareVar);
    
    if(i == 0){
      

      //set water switch
      if(compareVar == 1){
        waterOn = 1;
        Serial.println("Water ON");
        
        goto bailout;
      }
      else {
        waterOn = 0;
        Serial.println("water OFF");
      }
    }
    else if(i == 1){

      //set light switch
      if(compareVar == 1){
        lightOn = 1;
        Serial.println("Light ON");
        goto bailout;
      }
      else {
        lightOn = 0;
        Serial.println("light OFF");            
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
bailout:

and this is the called function:

```
//time compare with ON/OFF switch
int timeCompare(int hrOn, int minOn, int secOn, int hrOff, int minOff, int secOff, int timerSwitch){
  unsigned long int onTime = (hrOn*10000UL) + (minOn*100UL) + secOn;
  unsigned long int offTime = (hrOff*10000UL) + (minOff*100UL) + secOff;
  unsigned long int currentTime = (dt.hour*10000UL) + (dt.minute*100UL) + dt.second;




  if(timerSwitch == 1){
    if(onTime < currentTime && offTime > currentTime){
      compareVar = 1;
    }
    else {
      compareVar = 0;
    }
  }
 else if(timerSwitch == 0) {
    compareVar = 0;
  }
  

  //Serial.print("compare: "); Serial.println(compareVar);



  
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you exactly you are trying to do. I think it would help, if you would show us the code, that you already have. What does "hold it" means?

Comment: Sorry, I know it's confusing :-) I added the relevant parts of the code as the whole thing is already quite long. By holds it I mean I need to know if there is a 1 anywhere in the loop, but so far it just tells me if there is 1 in a single entry and then sets it to 0 with the next entry. I need to keep the 1 as long as there is 1 anywhere in the full run of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should really not use a global variable to get the result of your comparison function. That is only confusion and unnecessary complicated code. For that we have return values. So instead of setting the `compareVar` variable inside the `timeCompare()` function, you should just return the corresponding value. In the `timeCompare()` function replace

```
compareVar = 1;
```

with

```
return 1;
```

and

```
compareVar = 0;
```

with

```
return 0;
```

Then in your main code: As I understood, you only need `compareVar` in the for loops, so you could delete the globally defined `compareVar` and declare it directly before the for loops:

```
int compareVar = 0;
```

Now we can do the magic trick. We want to go through our for loops and get a result of `1`, if for any of the elements `timeCompare()` returns 1. For that we just doing an OR operation:

```
compareVar = compareVar || timeCompare(timeArray[i][j][k][0], timeArray[i][j][k][1], timeArray[i][j][k][2], timeArray[i][j][k][3], timeArray[i][j][k][4], timeArray[i][j][k][5], timeArray[i][j][k][6]);
```

This is a boolean OR `||`. In C++ zero is treated as `false`, while any other number is treated as `true`. We are starting with `compareVar` begin zero. When `timeCompare()` for the element returns also zero, it stays zero. If it returns 1, `compareVar` will become 1. If it returns 1 again, it will stay one. If it returns zero, it will stay zero.

So now you can check for `compareVar` after the for loops. It will be 1, if any of the elements gave you 1.

Similarly you could check for all elements returning 1, if you replace the OR `||` by an AND `&&` operation.

---

Lastly I want to strongly discourage you from using `goto`. It ignores some important principles and you can easily create really bad code with it. Refer to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto) to read more about it. I would say, that in every case you have better ways than `goto`. Here it seems, that you simply want to go out of both loops. I would pack these loops into a function, so that you could simply use a `return` statement to get out of them.

Comment: For another perspective: I use goto in exactly this (and *only* this) situation - breaking out of a nest of loops. I just make it super obvious that I'm doing it, why, and to where. Specifically, I always have (though I seldom need it) a `#define PUNT goto punt`, and keep the `punt:` label easy to notice....

Comment: ... This accomplishes two things: my code doesn't actually say "goto" (so the purists aren't so easily offended, though I'm sympathetic to their argument); and second, if I were to try to jump around in my code using this, or to create another nested-loops-with-breakout, my labels would conflict (multiple definitions) and prevent it. Either way, It gives me a heads-up that I need to re-think my coding structure and find a better way.